# JPEG Static Header And Append Image Data

Tags: base64, hex, jpeg

I am trying to do something like this: [Facebook Preview Photos](https://code.facebook.com/posts/991252547593574/the-technology-behind-preview-photos/).

As I understand it, they are utilizing small jpegs and the fact that all jpegs have similar "header" information to get a very small initial image preview to the user before the full image loads.

I want to do something similar, with the proposed workflow:

**1).** Leverage `data` and [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) to store the JPEG header in every `<image>` element.

**2).** Load the rest of the *small image* as an append to the Base64 header string.

**3).** Load the full image utilizing JavaScript onloads.

**For Reference: [JPEG Specs](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf)**

I have a hex editor, and I stripped the EXIF data, saved the header and now have an image that won't display. It is because I took too much away when I stripped the EXIF data, I believe. I used **[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure)** to decide where to clip the data, that is everything from `0xFF, 0xC0` to `0xFF, 0xDA` which I think was too much. I'm looking for an authoritative answer on how to get the most basic, renderable header before I can output the scan of the image. That is, how much of the hex data can I remove from the header before converting to Base64?

Facebook's Blog says:

> we looked through the rest of the standard JPEG header, the only
>   other table that could change with different images and options was
>   the Huffman table.

But it isn't clear to me on this reading whether that means they kept the rest of the header or they just manipulated this header.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they are using the same DHT and DQT markers to compress all their images. Their application knows the contents of those markers.

When they transmit their images, they strip out everything other than the SOF and SOS markers.

Their application client then assembles an SOI marker, the application DHT and DQT markers, the transmitted SOF and SOS markers, and an EOS marker. It then sends that stream to a decoder on the client side.

> As I understand it, they are utilizing small jpegs and the fact that all jpegs have similar "header" information to get a very small initial image preview to the user before the full image loads.

NO. They are compressing their images in such a way that the markers are the same.